# Let $M$ be any real $n \times n$ non-singular matrix, and let $A=M^TM$. Prove that $A$ is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, positive-definite

I know that $M$ being non-singular implies that:

- $\det(M) \neq 0$
- All eigenvalues of $M$ are nonzero
- The product of eigenvalues of $M = \det(M)$

and showing $A$ is positive definite would mean that:

- $\det(A) > 0$
- All eigenvalues of $A$ are positive
- 0 is not an eigenvalue of $A$

But I am not quite sure where $A=M^TM$ comes in, or how to manipulate that into showing $A$ is positive definite. Perhaps I can use the fact that $M$ is non-singular to show that $M^TM$ is positive definite?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: $ \langle Ax, x \rangle =\|Mx\|^{2} >0$ if $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have listed the properties of a positive definite matrix. The definition of a positive definite matrix is [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix):

A (symmetric) matrix $A$ is *positive definite* if $x^TAx > 0$ for all non zero vectors $x$.

In your problem $A = M^TM$, and therefore $x^TAx = x^TM^TMx = ||Mx||^2 \geq 0$.
Since $M$ is nonsingular we have $Mx \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$, and therefore we have $||Mx||^2 \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$. Thus $M^TM$ is positive definite.

Also note that the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, for instance, satisfies all the properties you have listed but it is still not positive definite (compute $x^TAx$ for $x=[1,1]$ for instance). So the properties you have listed is necessary but not sufficient for $A$ to be positive definite.

Comment: You cleared things up so much for me and explained this all so thoroughly. Thank you for the thoughtful answer!